# Scraping based on dropdown list

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping

```
#document
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body bgcolor="f2f2f2" leftmargin="0" topmargin="5">
          <style>  ...
          </style>
            <table width="100%"">
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <form id="frmFindParts"></form>
                        <td>
                            <select id="selYear" 
                            onchange="document.getElementById('frmFindParts').
                            submit();" name="year">    
                            <option value="">2015</option>
                         </td>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>...</tr></tbody></table>
```

**I need the xapth that should scrape the value 2015**

Here is my code when I exceuting I am getting null values to **tags  variable**

```
          var html = PageRetriever.ReadFromServer(pqi.URL, false);
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var tags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='selYear'] //option");
```

Here is the link
I am getting null value to var tags. My exact location is [link](http://www.partspros.com) . I have to scrape droppdownlist YEAR from 2014 to 1940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML-Content you want to select is not directly present in the described URL, but it is loaded in an iframe. You need to analyze [this URL](http://www.fastpivotsoftware.com/custom/partspros/search.php).

Comment: Page doesn't exist.